# What does notifyDataSetChanged() mean inside an adapter in viewPager2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, android-viewpager2

I'm using `viewPager2` in my application and adding/removing fragments. I'm trying to implement a feature to add/remove tabs at runtime and maybe understanding how `notifyDataSetChanged()` works might help me with my goal. For example: Changes in what, the mutableList maybe?

Here's my adapter (BTW, 'titles' is just a mutable list of movie titles):

```
class DynamicViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity):
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity){

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return DynamicFragment()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return titles.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
        return titles.contains(titles[itemId.toInt()])
    }

    fun addTab(title: String) {
        titles.add(title)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addTab(index: Int, title: String) {
        titles.add(index, title)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeTab(name: String) {
        titles.remove(name)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeTab(index: Int) {
        titles.removeAt(index)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `RecyclerView` as example, this widget needs data to bind with it, that is the **Data Set**, usually a `List<xxx>`:

`RecyclerView`: a `View` that display a list of information

`ReclerViewAdapter`: an **Adapter** that determines how each row should look like

`List<xxx>`: **Data Set** that you want to show in this `RecyclerView`

---

Say you have setup everything with your `RecyclerView`, then you modify (add/remove/update) some data of your `List<xxx>`, at this point you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ReclerViewAdapter` object to **REFRESH** your `RecyclerView`.

This works the same to `ViewPager2`. Only the **Data Set**  becomes `List<Fragment>`.

Comment: This answers a good part of my doubt, but at what point does the recyclerView know what list it's working with? Could it be in the getItemCount() function, or maybe outside of the Adapter?